# Flow-js: How to create a variable consistent with an intersection of array and object

Tags: flowtype

I have this valid flow-js definition for mysql :

```js
declare type QueryResults = Array<Object> &{
    insertId?: string | number,
    affectedRows?: number,
    changedRows?: number
};
```

And I've trying to create a variable that would be consistent with this definition. ([You can try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvIQE5kCGmAPAPIBGAVrgMboB8GO+AQiWADeqMKLABLAHYBnXGXQBJACYB+AFxhp6MlIDmYAD5hJAVwC2DOQBoRYylCht0uJQCVE09cfOWyNsWCsABaUkrou7gieGqYWcrYAvtx4YADCAkQAZGC8ANyoBTC46GCUAIwaRKQA2gC6qEUllABMlQLVggn1DcVgDBU5Ap09JQytg6SCUrLyyhoAzEkjgRqpqKzt9awAdNNyikoCAKyoQA)):

```js
/* @flow */
type A = Array<Object>
type B = {
    insertId?: string | number,
    affectedRows?: number,
    changedRows?: number
  }
type C = A & B;


let a1: A = []
let a2: A = [{}]

let b1: B = {}
let b2: B = {insertId: 3}

let c: C 
c = [] // Error, not complient with B
c.insertId = 5 // Error, not complient with A
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found out [see here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoALgTwA4FMwCCYAvIQE5kCGmAPAPIBGAVrgMboB8GO+AQiWADeqMKLABLAHYBnXGXQBJACYB+AFxhp6MlIDmYAD5hJAVwC2DOQBoRYylCht0uJQCVE09cfOWyNsWCsABaUkrou7gieGqYWcrYAvtx4YADCAkQAZGC8ANyoBTC46GCUAIwaRKQA2gC6qEUllABMlQLVggn1DcVgDBU5Ap09JQytg6SCUrLyyhoAzEkjgRrpkwkAdLgAHs6SSgAUdQCUQA)

```
c = {}.extend([])
```